# Running a .vbs file from .bat with variable path

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I'm trying to run a .vbs file through a batch program (.bat). The catch is that the .vbs file and the .bat file are in different directories. Also, I want to use a variable path so that any user can launch my .bat program through the correct directory.

A simple version of the .bat script would look like:

```
cscript "C:\users\Username\Directory\file.vbs"
```

But, I want to use a variable for the directory so that it looks like this:

```
cscript %variable% test.vbs
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%a in ("%cd%") do set user=%%a
set "base=c:\users\"
set "end=\Folder 1\Folder 2\"
set "basePath = %base%%user%%end%"
set "vbsName=test.vbs"
cscript %basePath% %vbsName%
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Users" directory of the current user is available in the `USERPROFILE` environment variable. The following would run the .vbs file from a batch file:

```
cscript "%USERPROFILE%\Folder 1\Folder 2\test.vbs"
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Please go ahead and mark this question as answered.